# Required knowledge before studying Naseem Nicolas Taleb books

Tags: book-recommendation, finance

I want to study Dynamic Hedging and Technical Incerto by Taleb. What should be the required math knowledge for these books?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the book available that you can look at (for example in a book store)? Text books usually have an introduction section where the target audience and prerequisites are explained.

Comment: I do not have a copy available. People can have a preview on google books or amazon or on his site.                                       
https://www.amazon.com/Dynamic-Hedging-Managing-Vanilla-Options/dp/0471152803